Find out the highest value that $\alpha(x, y)$ can take it, when $x$ and $y$ cover the interval $(0, \infty)$.
the problem
Let $k > −1$. For $x, y \in (0, \infty)$, we denote by $\alpha (x, y)$ the
smaller of the numbers $x, \frac{k}{x}+y, \frac{1}{y}$.
Find out the highest value that
$\alpha(x, y)$ can take it, when $x$ and $y$ cover the interval $(0, \infty)$.
my idea
Ok, sp I thought that we can let WLOG that $x\leq y$.
And I think we should take some cases like when $x\leq1$ and $y\geq 1$ just so we can decide which one of them would be the lowest in those cases, but I don't know how to do them...
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

When you say "$x$ and $y$ cover the interval $(0, \infty)$", do you mean $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, i.e. they are elements of the interval $(0, \infty)$?

@TheoBendit Yeah, thats what i mean

I claim that the maximum of $\alpha(x, y)$ is $\sqrt{k + 1}$ if $k \ge 0$. If we suppose $\alpha(x, y) \ge \sqrt{k+1}$, then we have $x \ge \sqrt{k+1}$ and $\frac{1}{y} \ge \sqrt{k+1}$. This implies that $\frac{k}{x} \le \frac{k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ (since $k \ge 0$) and $y \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$. As such,
$$\alpha(x, y) \le \frac{k}{x} + y \le \frac{k}{\sqrt{k+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} = \sqrt{k+1}.$$
This is, of course, achieved if we choose $x = \sqrt{k+1}$ and $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.
On the other hand, if $-1 < k < 0$, then there is no maximum, but only a supremum. I claim this supremum is $1$.
If we suppose $\alpha(x, y) \ge 1$, then we have $x \ge 1$ and $\frac{1}{y} \ge 1$, i.e. $y \le 1$. With this assumption that $k < 0$, we have $\frac{k}{x} + y < y \le 1$, so $\alpha(x, y) < 1$, a contradiction. Thus, $1$ is an upper bound that is not attained. On the other hand, by setting $y = 1$ and letting $x \to \infty$, we see that $\frac{k}{x} + y \to 1$, while $\frac{1}{y} = 1$, and $x$ will be eventually greater than both. Thus, $\alpha(x, 1) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$, proving the upper bound is indeed a supremum. Since this supremum is not attained, there is no maximum value of $\alpha(x, y)$.

so the solution is $\sqrt{k+1}$?

Yes, if $k \ge 0$. Otherwise, there is no maximum, but the supremum is $1$.
